# Laravel: Redirect url of type `user.php?id=3`

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I want to support old urls after switching to Laravel.

Since its not allowed to use a dot `.` in the routes, I am tryting to redirect `user.php?id=3` to `/user/3` in the `public/.htaccess` file.

I tried

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*)
  RewriteRule ^user\.php$ /user/$1
```

but its not working. The `RewriteRule` is ignored. Any suggestions why it is ignored?

This is my full Laravel `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*)
    RewriteRule ^user\.php$ /user/$1

    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
    # [NC] is a case-insensitive match
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "_Since its not allowed to use a dot . in the routes_" Dots ARE allowed in routes, just not in route variables. No need for all the redirects

Comment: @kerbholz I wish you were right! If I try `Route::get('/user.php',function(){
  dd('test');
})` then `/user.php` returns `No input file specified. `

Comment: Hm, strange. `Route::get('/user.py', function () {dd('test');});` works like a charm here, using `Laravel Framework 5.5.28` and no Apache, so **NO** RewriteRules.

Comment: @kerbholz okay I found the problem - it works on my productions server with apache, but its not workin on Homestead with Nginx https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/routes-with-php-file-extensions ... thanks for that comment.. All I need is my production server to work.

Comment: Nice, glad it works

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^user.php$ /user/%1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried that even with `^user\.php$` but it does not work.

Comment: You need to improve the answer by explaining what this does.

Answer (score 0):

For back reference of `RewriteCond`, you need to use `%1` instead `$1`.

Check this code :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^user\.php$ /user/%1 [L]
```

> ***RewriteCond backreferences***: These are backreferences of the form %N (0 <= N <= 9). %1 to %9 provide access to the grouped parts (again, in
>   parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the
>   current set of conditions. %0 provides access to the whole string
>   matched by that pattern.

Reference : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond